# R Shiny Error: "cannot find function "shinyServer"

Tags: r

New to R shiny. Simulating the shiny server found on [Github](http://gist.github.com/wch/4034323.2) but for a logistic distribution instead of the quadratic, linear and LOESS shown. In my code, the checkboxes are taken out and the y-variable is a categorical variable. R does not display errors  until the ending with }) in the console. R stated "could not find function "shinyServer". I did not try the app with runApp() because the error occurred.

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)

hw <- read.csv("LogitTV.csv")

in_range <- function(x, range) {
 x >= min(range) & x <= max(range)

}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

 limit_data_range <- function() {

     if (is.null(input$x_range) || is.null(input$y_range)) {
         return(NULL)
     }

     hw_sub <- hw[in_range(hw[[input$x_var]], input$x_range) &
                 in_range(hw[[input$y_var]], input$y_range), ]

     hw_sub
 }



 output$main_plot <- renderPlot({


     hw_sub <- limit_data_range()

     if (is.null(hw_sub))
         return()


     xdat <- hw[[input$x_var]]
         ydat <- hw[[input$y_var]]





     if(input$mod_logistic)
         point_alpha <- 0.5  
     else
         point_alpha <- 1






     p <- ggplot(hw_sub, mapping = aes_mapping) +
         points +
         theme_bw() +
         scale_colour_hue(l = 40) +
         scale_shape(solid = FALSE) +

         scale_x_continuous(limits = range(xdat)) +
         scale_y_continuous(limits = range(ydat))




     if (max(input$x_range) != max(xdat)) {
             p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = max(input$x_range), linetype = "dashed",
                                 alpha = 0.3)
         }
         if (min(input$x_range) != min(xdat)) {
         p <- p + geom_vline(xintercept = min(input$x_range), linetype = "dashed",
                             alpha = 0.3)
     }

     if (max(input$y_range) != max(ydat)) {
             p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = max(input$y_range), linetype = "dashed",
                                 alpha = 0.3)
         }
         if (min(input$y_range) != min(ydat)) {
         p <- p + geom_hline(yintercept = min(input$y_range), linetype = "dashed",
                             alpha = 0.3)
     }


     if (input$mod_logistic) {
         p <- p + geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, size = 0.75,    
                             linetype = "dotdash")
         }

     print
 })



 output$x_range_slider <- renderUI({
         xmin <- floor(min(hw[[input$x_var]]))
         xmax <- ceiling(max(hw[[input$x_var]]))

     sliderInput(inputId = "x_range",
                 label = paste("Limit range"),
                 min = xmin, max = xmax, value = c(xmin, xmax))
 })

 output$y_range_slider <- renderUI({
         ymin <- floor(min(hw[[input$y_var]]))
         ymax <- ceiling(max(hw[[input$y_var]]))

     sliderInput(inputId = "y_range",
                 label = paste("Limit range"),
                 min = ymin, max = ymax, value = c(ymin, ymax))
 })





 make_model <- function(model_type, formula, ...) {

     hw_sub <- limit_data_range()
     if (is.null(hw_sub))
         return()



     do.call(model_type, args = list(formula = formula, data = quote(hw_sub), ...))
 }

 output$mod_logistic_text <- renderPrint({
         formula <- paste(input$y_var, "~", input$x_var)

 })
```

})
Error: could not find function "shinyServer"

Comment: Shouldn't you say `require(shiny)` at the top of your script?

Comment: This looks like a server.R file. You should also have a ui.R file.  Put both of them in a directory, then in R, call `runApp` and pass it the path to the directory.  If the directory is called "myApp", then in R you'd run `library(shiny);runApp("myApp", port=8100)`

Comment: @GSee I will put in the ui.R file in the same directory above the server script. Does "myApp" refer to the name working directory or name of the directory that the ui.r and server are put in (tab at top left of window)?                                                I set working directory with setwd("~/Home Automation") performed runApp("~/Home Automation/", port=8100) but got Error in startAppDir(port = port) : 
  Neither ui.R nor a www subdirectory was found in /Users/scdavis6/Home Automation

Comment: "myApp" refers to the name of the directory that contains ui.R and server.R.  I suggest you work through [the tuturial](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/).

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue thanks for pointing that out, I put in require(shiny) at the top.

Comment: @GSee thanks for clarifying, the name of directory is LogitTV.R. The [Shiny tutorial (http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#ui-and-server) state, "To get started building the application, create a new empty directory wherever you’d like, then create empty ui.R and server.R files within in." Since identifying the working directory, I wrote runApp("~/LogitTV.R", port=8100) but still got runApp("~/LogitTV", port=8100)
Error in setwd(appDir) : cannot change working directory. Do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: Did you create files named "ui.R" and "server.R" in the "LogitTV" directory and put code in them?